# add 'Working Papers' Section (within publications) to hugo-academic site

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

I am using R blogdown package to create my personal website. I am basing it on the hugo-academic theme ([code here](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic))

I would like to add a "working papers" section to the publications.
In my discipline Economics we normally have

- "working papers" (pdf is available)
- "work in progress" (no pdf yet)
- "publications"

How can I add that?

Do I need to change the internals of the hugo-academic theme? (I am an R user/programmer with little webdev knowledge)

I  posted as github issue: [hugo-academic/issues/416](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/416)

Edit: I would also like to have the "Selected Publications" section disapear. I could not do that even after setting `selected = false` on all the publications .md files. This was asked in github issue: [hugo-academic/issues/417](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/417)

Edit2: I would also like to add a new "Work in progress" section ([hugo-academic/issues/418](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/418)).

Edit3: @jsb answer bellow does not alter how the papers are grouped by type (working paper, work in progress, peer-reviewd), which is my main concern. But it does add these cathegories to the metadata (and fixes question two).

They way I understand it now, I would have to add new widgets for "Working Papers" and "Work in Progress". I think I could create them by analogy from the existing widgets.

Where in the code are the widgets are defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your first question: I don't think this is possible in the current version of the academic theme. However, what you can do, is to use the publication types that are defined in the `config.toml` file. In this file, there is a list of publication types that are used to categorize publications. It includes a type called "work in progress". You can also add your own publication types to this list, like so:

```
  publication_types = [
    'Uncategorized',  # 0
    'Conference proceedings',  # 1
    'Journal',  # 2
    'Work in progress',  # 3
    'Technical report',  # 4
    'Book',  # 5
    'Book chapter',  # 6
    'working paper', # 7
    'peer-reviewed' # 8
  ]
```

For each publication Markdown file, change the `publication types` parameter to the wanted type, e.g. `publication_types = ["7"]` for a working paper. The effect is visible when you click on the "Details" link for a publication listed under "Publications" or "Selected Publications".

Answering your second question: to delete a section, delete the corresponding Markdown file from the "content/home" folder. Alternatively, move the unwanted Markdown file to a new folder, e.g. "_not_used", in the "content" folder.

Update: OP found the answer himself, and I am putting it here for future reference:

> I found the solution, all I had to do was duplicate the
>   publications.md file, naming it publications_working_papers.md,
>   publications_book_chapters.md for instance. In each file use widget =
>   "publications" and adjust the publication_type accordingly. And also the
>   weight to determine the order.

Comment: this is a bit weird. Deleting the content/home/publications_selected.md  file made the section disapear if all publications had "selected = false" setting. If there was "selected = true" on any publication  then the "Recent Publications" reapeared.

Comment: I managed to hack this by changint the title = "Selected Publications" to title = "Working Papers" in the publications_selected.md file. But this is probably not the correct way to do it.

Comment: I also tryed to add a content/home/working_papers.md file but the site would noe compile with that

Comment: I see your edit. But, weirdly, changing publication_types = (to 3 or 7, for instance) does not change the "section" of the page where the citation apears. publication_types = ["3"] does nothing to the appearance of the website

Comment: I have changed person-re-identification.md  and clothing-search.md in content/publication/ for publication_types  3 (Work in progress) and 7 (working paper) as suggested, "], but nothing changed. the still show up as in the "Recent Publications" section of the rendered site

Comment: OBS: I also changed cofing.tolm as indicated above

Comment: I want there to be a "section", just as we have for "Selected Publications" and "Recent Publications" for "Work in Progress" and "Working Papers", with the corresponding papers in each section

Comment: What is the effect you see on your end? Do you see any changes in the website ?

Comment: I am afraid we would need to add specific widgets for "working_paper" and "work_in_progress" to the theme (as there exist for widget = "publications" and widget = "publications_selected")

Comment: I found the solution, all I had to do was duplicate the publications.md file, namining it publications_working_papers.md, publications_book_chapters.md for instance. In each file use widget = "publications" and ajust the publication_type acordingly. And also the weigth to determine the order. Please include this in your answer so I can mark it as a solution

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do this in the current hugo-academic setup by using "featured" widgets. In my case I wanted a section for books, one for journal articles and one for working papers.

In the `home` folder, I made a copy of `featured.md` and named it `working-papers.md`. I then renamed the original `featured.md` to `books.md`.

From there, I opened `books.md`, set `weight:` to `20`, changed the `title:` to `Book` and set `filters: publication_type:` to `"5"`.

Next, I opened the new `working-papers.md` file, set `weight:` to `30`, changed `title:` to `Working Papers` and set `filters: publication_type:` to  `"3"`.

Then I renamed `publications.md` to `articles.md`, opened the file, set `weight:` to `25`, `title:` to  `Journal Articles` and set `exclude_featured:` to `true`. This ensures that the books and working papers that I want to include in the "featured" widgets do not also appear in my "Journal Articles" section.

Finally, I set `featured:` to `true` in the `index.md` files for my book and working papers in `content\publication` to populate the new "Book" and "Working Papers" featured widgets.

This gives me three consecutive sections on [my website](https://www.emmanuelteitelbaum.com/) listing my book, journal articles and working papers.

I initially tried it the way you suggested in your note (copying and renaming the `publications.md` file). You can still do it like this, but the current setup uses the `pages` widget for `publications.md`. So instead of changing the widget type, you have to change `page_type:` to `publication` and then set `publication_type:` to whatever type of publication you want to include on that page. This worked OK but strange things happened when I clicked on the "See All Publications" link at the bottom of my "Journal Articles" section, so I ended up using the featured widgets instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant @lucasmation, but for 'Selected Publications' to be turned off, you'd have to go to `contents>home>publications_selected.md` and set the widget to be `false`. Hope this helps.

```
# Selected Publications widget.
# This widget displays publications from `content/publication/` which have
# `selected = true` in their `+++` front matter.
widget = "publications_selected"
active = false
date = 2012-01-01T00:00:00
```